# Codeception seeInDatabase() doesn't work for me

Tags: laravel, codeception

I am really stuck with this acceptance test.

My code is this

```
$I->click('Submit');
$I->see('Client Added');
$I->seeInDatabase('customers',[
    'afm'=>'111'
    ]);
```

Everything passes until the line with "seeInDatabase". Log gives me this error "ALERT: No matching records found Failed asserting that '0' is greater than 0.".

I checked the database settings

```
modules:
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbtesting'
            user: 'test'
            password: 'test'
            dump: app/tests/_data/dump.sql
            populate: true
            cleanup: true
```

Seems fine to me. I double checked with seeInDatabase() with a row that I know its there and yeah, Its working just fine. ( not a PDO issue or anything like that then)

So I forced the creation in my controller after the "POST" of the form just to make sure

```
public function store(){

\Customer::create(['afm'=>111]);

return \Redirect::route('customers.index')->with('successMsg',Client Added');
}
```

Again, I couldn't verify this new row. Any idea how to solve this?

//// UPDATE /////

When I am replacing Eloquent Insert with vanilla PDO code, everything is ok. How to fix this? (Full info [here](https://laracasts.com/forum/969-codeception-and-laravel/p1#p5434) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the documentation

> cleanup: true - all db queries will be run in transaction, which will
>   be rolled back at the end of test.

So normally something like this should work (functional.suite.yml)

```
class_name: TestGuy
modules:
    enabled: [Filesystem, TestHelper, Laravel4, Db]
    config:
        Laravel4:
            cleanup:false
```

But in my case didn't solve anything. So I forced it by altering line 59 in /Module/Laravel4.php

```
cleanup = true

TO

cleanup  = false
```

And finally, I have a fix for this issue, although its not the ideal because of composer updates.

Answer (score 6):

I just hit the same issue and apparently we have "seeRecord" helper method available in Laravel4 module to check records. Works like a charm.

```
$I->seeRecord('customers', ['afm' => '111']);
```

Comment: Sweet - that sorted me out straight away and looks neater than the accepted answer.