# In codeception functional test seeInDatabase not works from laravel

Tags: laravel, codeception, laravel-5

I am using `codeception` for testing in `laravel 5.2`.
Here is my `codeception.yml` file:

```
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests_codecept
    log: tests_codecept/_output
    data: tests_codecept/_data
    support: tests_codecept/_support
    envs: tests_codecept/_envs
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: false
    memory_limit: 1024M
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
modules:
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=kartice_test'
            user: '*******'
            password: '*******'
            dump: tests_codecept/_data/dump.sql
            populate: true
            cleanup: true
            reconnect: true
```

and here is `functional.suite.yml` file:

```
class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
        # add framework module here
        - \Helper\Functional
        - Asserts
        - Laravel5:
            environment_file: .env.testing
        - Db
```

here is my `test method`:

```
public function provera_dodavanja_novog_klijenta(FunctionalTester $I)
{

    $this->authenticate($I);

    $I->amOnPage('/kancelarija/komitenti/create');
    $I->see('Kreiranje novog komitenta');
    $I->fillField('input[name=komitent_code]', 'kom1');
    $I->fillField('input[name=komitent_name]', 'Komitent 1');
    $I->click('btnSave');
    $I->seeInDatabase('komitenti', ['code' => 'kom1', 'name' => 'Komitent 1']);
    $I->see('Komitent Komitent 1 je uspešno kreiran.');

}
```

Running functional test fails with message:

```
 Step  I see in database "komitenti",{"code":"kom1","name":"Komitent 1"}
 Fail  No matching records found for criteria {"code":"kom1","name":"Komitent 1"} in table komitenti
Failed asserting that 0 is greater than 0.
```

What I am doing wrong?

I have seen question [Codeception seeInDatabase() doesn't work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492531/codeception-seeindatabase-doesnt-work-for-me) but this didn't helpe me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use`seeRecord` method instead of `seeInDatabase`. I don't know why but for me first one was working and second one - not.

Comment: Hard to say, but in documentation there is no info that it could not work in Laravel. I wasted a lot of time about a year ago, to solve this and simply change to using `seeRecord` method

Answer (score 0):

I use gulp tdd and when testing forms come across this error.
Please check:

1. You added this to Requests

   `<YourFormRequest>use App\Http\Requests\<YourFormRequest>;`
2. Ensure the Model for your table is mass assignable

   `protected $fillable = ['tableField1', 'tableField2']`