# Codeception seeInDatabase() not working as expected

Tags: codeception

I have problems getting codeceptions `seeInDatabase()` to work. This is my Cest:

```
public function testContactMailCheckbox(AcceptanceTester $I) {
    $I->scrollTo("#adminMailSettingsForm", 0, -200);
    $I->seeInDatabase("pib_users", [
        "user_email" => "admin-cest@example.org",
        "user_receive_contact_notification" => 0
    ]);

    $I->click("//label[@for='contactMailNotification']", "#adminMailSettingsForm");
    $I->waitForJS("return $.active == 0;",10);
    $I->wait(100);
    $I->seeInDatabase("pib_users", [
        "user_email" => "admin-cest@example.org",
        "user_receive_contact_notification" => 1
    ]);
}
```

The first `seeInDatabase()` passes, everything is fine. I can verify that this seeInDatabase-Assertion works correctly, by changing the default-data in my database dump. When I change the default data to `"user_receive_contact_notification" => 1`, the first `seeInDatabase` fails, which means it is working correctly.

I use `$I->wait(100)` to verify, that there are no synchronisation-issues. During this timespan I can check via phpMyAdmin, that the row was indeed updated correctly. That means the test should pass.

Here is my Db-config:

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
  enabled:
      - WebDriver:
          url: 'http://pib.local/'
          window_size: false # disabled in ChromeDriver
          port: 5555
          browser: chrome
          capabilities:
            chromeOptions:
              args: ["--headless", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1080"]

      - \Helper\Acceptance
      - Sequence
      - \Helper\DbHelper
  config:
      \Helper\DbHelper:
          user: "root"
          password: ""
          dsn: "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pib"
          cleanup: true
          dump: 'tests/database_dump_tests.sql'
          populate: true
          reconnect: true
  step_decorators: ~
```

My DbHelper contains only a single function:

```
class DbHelper extends \Codeception\Module\Db
{
    public function putInDatabase($table, $data, $insertOnlyIfNotExisting = true) {
        // if ignoreDuplicateError is true, only execute insert when not existing already
        if($this->countInDatabase($table, $data) == 0 | !$insertOnlyIfNotExisting) {
            $this->_insertInDatabase($table, $data);
        }
    }
}
```

This might be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492531/codeception-seeindatabase-doesnt-work-for-me). I don't use Laravel though, so just using the `seeRecord()`-helper isn't going to help me.

Comment: This is a really odd issue. What's the type of user_receive_contact_notification column? is it ENUM or some INT type? Also it could be useful to see full content of acceptance.suite.yml (mask the passwords and other sensitive information).

Comment: Here you go. user_receive_contact_notification is not only an awfully named column, but of boolean/tinyint(1)-type as well ;) It stores whether or not a user should receive a notification for new messages